# Reduce space between fileInput and text in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Could you help me to reduce the space between fileInput and text in Shiny? I would like to leave something similar to the Figure that I have attached. The executable code is below.

Thank you!

```
runApp(
  list(ui = fluidPage(
    fileInput("data", h3("Excel database import")), uiOutput("tab"),
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    url <- a("Google Homepage", href="https://www.google.com/")
    output$tab <- renderUI({
      tagList("Access the page:", url)
    })
  })
)
```

#### How is it when executing shiny:

[image]

#### How I would like it to be:

[image]

Comment: Which text? There are multiple elements here. You could be referring to the h3/header or the "access the page". (Or something else?) Have you tried any CSS styling? That's the canonical way to address whitespace, even if it is not always intuitive in/around shiny objects.

Comment: Thank you for reply friend. Sorry if it was unclear. Precisely, I wanted to reduce this space between fileInput and the text: Access the page. In the image the shape I would like is presented. Would you know how I could do that ?? I leave a picture above as it is, and also as I would like it to be. Thankis again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply some `style` to it and adjust it using `margin-top`:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(
    list(ui = fluidPage(
        tags$head(tags$style(' #tab {margin-top:-30px;}')),
        fileInput("data", h3("Excel database import")), uiOutput("tab"),
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session){
        url <- a("Google Homepage", href="https://www.google.com/")
        output$tab <- renderUI({
            tagList("Access the page:", url)
        })
    })
)
```

Comment: Thanks friend for reply!

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively to Pork Chop's solution, you can insert a `div` element with a negative `margin-top` between the two elements you want to be closer:

```
ui = fluidPage(
  fileInput("data", h3("Excel database import")), 
  div(style = "margin-top: -30px"),
  uiOutput("tab")
)
```

Comment: Thanks friend for reply!

Comment: This worked for me too! Unlike some other answers, this also just applies itself to the nearest element instead of the entire document.